# Mounting an NFS share as / on many client hosts

Tags: linux, nfs, network-interface

I want to set up several PCs to mount an NFS version 4 share as the / filesystem.  This is on Linux 4.4.0 (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS).  I have seen this kind of thing done elsewhere with "thin clients" (diskless PCs).  Then I can take the disk drives out of these PCs and use them elsewhere.  I believe the first issue will be to get the PCs to boot from the server over the network.  Everything, including the server, is all on the same subnet which is a 1 Gbps LAN.  There is a separate router to reach the internet (this works OK).  If I need different network cards to make network booting work, I can get them; let me know what is best for this, but I believe all 1 Gbps cards are modern enough to support network booting.  These cards are Intel brand but I don't have the model.  The next issue I suspect is how to get 30 different PCs to not collide on the same files.  I believe a lot of this means different file names for each PC.  How do I set that up?  And how do I get them to mount the NFS as / (even for the testing period when they initially boot from their hard drive)?  Should I use NFS3 for this kind of thing?

Comment: There are no major technical problems with that setup, but your users will hate you for it.  After maintaining it for a week you'll probably hate yourself for it, too.

Comment: @SatōKatsura the original design of this school lab was to be thin clients.  the disk drives will be used to build a 2nd lab next year.  once done i get to keep half of them personally in exchange for setting this up and the rest go to faculty as backup dives.  they are 4TB external USB.

Comment: Note that it may be a bad idea for several clients to mount the same root directory, if that root file system also includes `/etc` and `/var` (or other directories that should not be shared).

Comment: @Kusalananda i have seen thin-client networks before, although i did not look at these details.  how would they have done this for many diskless hosts mounting from a single server?  different directories on the exported space for each client mounting a different directory for its `/etc` and `/var`?